# User database schema - over normalization or not?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to create a user's database schema. I could consider "user" entity like a object with its properties, like so:

- Users(table)

  - id
  - firstname
  - lastname
  - email
  - password
  - salt
  - description (text)
  - category (tinyint - foreign keys)
  - sub_category (tinyint - foreing keys)
  - status (varchar, active, banned, waiting (waiting for approval))
  - created (datetime)
  - edited (datetime)
  - deleted (datetime)

Otherwise I could separate description, into users_description table (1-1 relationship), category in user_category(1-1), users_status(1-1), users_datetime(1-1) (for created, edited...) and join them with a join.

Which form is better? I think than second hypothesis is "over normalized", in theory is better but in practically doesn't. I use Mysql and php.

Comment: I don't at all see the benefit of splitting your original structure.

Comment: For example, if a user may belong to multiple categories, then splitting for category table will be necessary, but otherwise it doesn't seem to.

Comment: the doubt borns because description, category, sub_category, edited, deleted are not required (nullable) and I thought than it's a problem with normalization :)

Comment: If category table and subcategory table is very small as compared to user profile table then normalization is helpful otherwise you can go with your first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is a good list of things that are sometimes "overnormalized".

Do not normalize "continuous" things, such as `DATETIME`, numbers, floats, etc.  Some day you may need to fetch, say, the rows within some datetime range; normalization would make that clumsy and inefficient.

Things like "status" and "flags" and "yes/no", etc are often better handled with a simple `ENUM`.

Assuming "category" (and maybe "sub-category") has some other information associated with it, it is probably fine to normalize it.  If it is a "many-to-many" relationship between users and categories, then you need 2 extra tables, and it is not really "normalization" but a "relationship".  (You mentioned 1-1; I suspect that was a mistake.)

`description TEXT` -- This smells like a field that is never duplicated, so normalization will neither save space nor simplify changing it.  Don't normalize.